# Segmentation fault in function of TAD

Tags: c

I need to create a TAD that will read a PGM image, do Convolution operation and output this image, implementing the functions:

/***********************I implemented the following

Comment: Probably it is not the compiler that gives a segmentation fault, but your program. Please use a debugger, at least to find out where the seg fault occurrs.

Comment: perhaps `saida = img;` in `Convolucao` is wrong. and `free(new_img);` can't this.

Comment: I used the debugger but without success. How should I do to saida receive img

Comment: Please don't vandalize your posts.

Answer (score 1):

The lines

```
new_img[img->lin+2][0]=img->img[img->lin+1][1];//inferior esquerdo
new_img[0][img->col+2]=img->img[1][img->col+1];//superior direito
new_img[0][0]=img->img[1][1];//superior esquerdo
new_img[img->lin+2][img->col+2]=img->img[img->lin+1][img->col+1];//inferior direito
```

look wrong as you dimensioned `new_img` as

```
unsigned char new_img[img->lin+2][img->col+2];
```

so you can only access up to `img->lin+1` on the first index and `img->col+1` on the second. Similarly `img->img` has dimensions `img->lin` and `img->col` so you've gone out of bounds there too.

Also, looks like you have a typo in

```
    if(somatorio<=0) saida->img[contador1-1][contador2-1]=0;
        else if(somatorio>=255) saida->img[contador1-1][contador2-1]=255;
            else saida->img[contador1-1][contador1-1]=somatorio;
```

That last line looks like it should have `contador2-1` as the second array index.

Comment: Yes, sorry. But the problem continues :/

Comment: I would suggest updating the code in your question with the fixes for the problems I've outlined and then also posting the debugger backtrace at the point at which the application crashes.